# Stuck at splash screen of ubuntu when changing from Lightdm to GDM

Tags: 14.10, display-manager

After changing the display manager from `lightdm` to `GDM`, when I boot Ubuntu it gets stuck at the splash screen.

What could be the reason and how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you switch to virtual terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1? Can you [turn on boot messages](/q/25022/175814) and see if there's something related to GDM? Please also post the content of `/var/log/boot.log`, `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, and `/var/log/gdm/:0-*.log` (either [from the virtual terminal](/q/440087/175814) or with a live medium and the “Try Ubuntu” option).

Answer (score 0):

If you can get into tty1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, log in and do
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. You will be prompted to choose default desktop manager. Select lightdm. Reboot with `sudo shutdown -r now`

If you are keen on changing the desktop manager, there are `lightdm-gtk-greeter` and `lightdm-webkit-greeter` , which are pretty much ok,too. Install the one you like, for example, `sudo apt-get install lightmd-gtk-greeter`, edit the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file and add the following

> [SeatDefaults]
>
> greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I am able to login with guest account..But when try to do login with my account...a blank page with ubuntu icon appears...no desktop nothing